# CSS: Change style of page from other site in my site

Tags: html, css

I need to change style of block i get data of it from other site, the URL set in    iframe like:

```
<iframe id="match_center_iframe" frameborder="0" src="http://matchcenter.super.ae/adsiframes/mc_matches.php?compid=10" height="650px" width="95%" scrolling="no" align="center" style="display:block; margin: auto;"></iframe>
```

and my site is not http://matchcenter.super.ae, Its other domain, So how can do this ?

Comment: _"Its other domain, So how can do this ?"_ - not at all, of course.

Comment: can explain your comment ?

Comment: You can not change the formatting of other sites you embed via an iframe, because that would be a huge security risk.